# how to add a feature in Nitrogen opendaylight?

Tags: maven, apache-karaf, opendaylight

I am trying to add some feature to my open daylight project (e.g. l2switch, dlux, rest,...).
I used to edit the features.xml and the pom.xml for add there features in Carbon release. I am currently using Nitrogen release, when adding these dependencies in my features pom.xml file, I am still unable to detect the features when I login to my karaf (using feature:install/list).

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.opendaylight.netconf</groupId>
  <artifactId>features-restconf</artifactId>
  <classifier>features</classifier>
  <version>${restconf.version}</version>
  <type>xml</type>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.opendaylight.dluxapps</groupId>
  <artifactId>features-dluxapps</artifactId>
  <classifier>features</classifier>
  <version>${dluxapps.version}</version>
  <type>xml</type>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

am I missing something else? when I try to add repositories,as I previously did in carbon-release. The feature.xml it automatically re-generated and all my editing is removed.

I am using Nitrogen release by defining and -DarchetypeVersion=1.4.0 when generating my maven artifact.

Answer (score 0):

See the upstream configuration management tooling for running-code examples being used constantly in downstreams like OPNFV.

```
  # Configuration of Karaf features to install
  file { 'org.apache.karaf.features.cfg':
    ensure => file,
    path   => '/opt/opendaylight/etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg',
    # Set user:group owners
    owner  => 'odl',
    group  => 'odl',
  }
  $features_csv = join($opendaylight::features, ',')
  file_line { 'featuresBoot':
    path  => '/opt/opendaylight/etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg',
    line  => "featuresBoot=${features_csv}",
    match => '^featuresBoot=.*$',
  }
```

[puppet-opendaylight, manifests/config.pp, stable/nitrogen](https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/gitweb?p=integration/packaging/puppet-opendaylight.git;a=blob;f=manifests/config.pp;h=7f0fa978c7924e85edf15d4f4d8ce5f2f53d040b;hb=refs/heads/stable/nitrogen#l15)

So basically you shouldn't be editing the XML directly, you should edit the configuration that generates the XML. I'm surprised that worked in Carbon.

I recommend directly using upstream configuration management tooling, like [puppet-opendaylight](https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/gitweb?p=integration/packaging/puppet-opendaylight.git;a=tree) or [ansible-opendaylight](https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/gitweb?p=integration/packaging/ansible-opendaylight.git;a=tree), vs trying to figure out the configuration knobs yourself, duplicating effort. If you're doing a more complex deployment, look at the [OPNFV installer](http://artifacts.opnfv.org/apex/docs/installation-instructions/index.html) scenarios (that build on these ODL tools) vs trying to solve that very hard problem yourself.

Comment: thank you so much, for your reply.. I am actually new to opendaylight development. I am developing a simple application that listens to all packets "PacketProcessingListener", extracts the header information and save it in a tree in order to be used through REST.  is there any guidance or simple tutorial on how to use puppet-opendaylight or ansible-opendaylight? for the pom.xml should I also use these tools?

Comment: Bit of docs [here](http://docs.opendaylight.org/projects/integration-packaging/en/latest/configuration-management.html), some more docs in the READMEs in each repo.